# Determine what version of Mono is running on linux?

Tags: linux, mono

Is there a command line I can run to determine what version of Mono I am running on Linux?  I am using Ubuntu and I it is command line only (no X Windows installed).

Answer (score 116, accepted):

`mono --version` should tell you.

Comment: Which part of that contains the mono version? Is it this: Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.0 ((no/7c7fcc7 Tue Jul 23 19:59:39 EDT 2013)?

Comment: @PsychoDad yes, you have version 3.2.0